# How to find the posterior predictive distribution of a hierarchical model where the dependent variable is group indexed?

Tags: multilevel-analysis, markov-chain-montecarlo, hierarchical-bayesian

I have data on $i = 1, \ldots, N$ units which belong in $s = 1, \ldots, M$ groups. The data is indexed by these two indices. I have an independent binary data $X$ corresponding to dependent binary data $Y$. The hierarchical model is given by:

$$
X_{is} \sim Bern(\theta_{s, y})\\
Y_{is} \sim Bern(\pi_s)\\
\theta_{s,y} \sim Beta(a_y,b_y)\\
\pi_s \sim Unif(0,1)\\
a_y \sim Gamma(0.5,0.5)\\
b_y \sim Gamma(0.5,0.5)\\
$$

I am wondering how I can obtain posterior predictive draws of $Y$ and $X$ after running MCMCs. For example, suppose I wanted to draw $Y$. I would first take a set of draws from the chain on $\pi_s$, then plug this into $Bern(\pi_s)$ to get a single draw of $Y$. However, each draw of $\pi$ from the chain consists of $s$ values. Which of these $s$ values do I plug into the Bernoulli?

Do I look at my **observed** data and randomly select a unit, and record their group membership indicator $s$, and select the value of a chain draw $\pi_s$ off that?